# Custom Post Archive Page not working

Tags: posts, customization

```php
add_action('init', function() {
    register_post_type('vendorpost', [
        'label' => __('Vendor Post', 'txtdomain'),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-users',
        'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'tag', 'revisions', 'comments'],
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'vendorposts'],
        'taxonomies' => ['vendorpost_author', 'vendorpost_genre'],
        'labels' => [
            'singular_name' => __('Vendor Post', 'txtdomain'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add new vendor post', 'txtdomain'),
            'new_item' => __('New Vendor Post', 'txtdomain'),
            'view_item' => __('View Vendor Post', 'txtdomain'),
            'not_found' => __('No Vendor Post found', 'txtdomain'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Vendor Post found in trash', 'txtdomain'),
            'all_items' => __('All Vendor Post', 'txtdomain'),
            'insert_into_item' => __('Insert into Vendor Post', 'txtdomain')
        ],      
    ]);
 
    register_taxonomy('vendorpost_category', ['vendorpost'], [
        'label' => __('Categories', 'txtdomain'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'vendorposts-category'],
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'labels' => [
            'singular_name' => __('Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'all_items' => __('All Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'view_item' => __('View Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'new_item_name' => __('New Category Name', 'txtdomain'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Categorys', 'txtdomain'),
            'parent_item' => __('Parent Category', 'txtdomain'),
            'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Category:', 'txtdomain'),
            'not_found' => __('No Category found', 'txtdomain'),
        ]
    ]);
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('vendorpost_category', 'vendorpost');
 
    register_taxonomy('vendorpost_tag', ['vendorpost'], [
        'label' => __('Tags', 'txtdomain'),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'vendorposts-tag'],
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'labels' => [
            'singular_name' => __('Tag', 'txtdomain'),
            'all_items' => __('All Tags', 'txtdomain'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Tag', 'txtdomain'),
            'view_item' => __('View Tag', 'txtdomain'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Tag', 'txtdomain'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Tag', 'txtdomain'),
            'new_item_name' => __('New Tag Name', 'txtdomain'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Tags', 'txtdomain'),
            'popular_items' => __('Popular Tags', 'txtdomain'),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate Tags with comma', 'txtdomain'),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from most used Tags', 'txtdomain'),
            'not_found' => __('No Tags found', 'txtdomain'),
        ]
    ]);
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('vendorpost_tag', 'vendorpost');
});
```

Comment: i created a archive-vendorposts.php page but when I click on category it redirect to archive.php please help.

Comment: Your archive should be `archive-vendorpost.php`.

Comment: i using archive-vendorpost.php but not working

Comment: You should probably include the contents of `archive-vendorpost.php` as well as the problem may be that it isn't set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to see the archive of you custom posts the archive will be:

`archive-vendorpost.php`

When you switch to a category there is a separate template wordpress uses:

`taxonomy-vendorpost_category.php`

Remember also, that you'll need to visit the permalinks page to reset them after as your code doesn't do that for you.

I've tested your code on my system and everything is working properly for me.